# Can't get message from the database table. ErrorException say:count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: database, laravel, fetch

**MessageController.php**

```
public function getMessages(){
    $messages = Message::all();

    return view('messages')->with('messages','$messages');
}
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/messages','MessagesController@getMessages');
```

**messages.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')

    <h1>Messages</h1>

    @if(count($messages) > 0)
        @foreach($messages as $message)
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">Name: {‌{$message->name}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Email: {‌{$message->email}}</li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Message: {‌{$message->message}}</li>
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    @endif

@endsection
```

---

Inside the layout folder / app.blade.php is my layout template blade.

The error message:

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements
>   Countable (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\resources\views\messages.blade.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: @Devon I don't think the OP realized the quotes. This isn't a duplicate per se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is you are passing a string, not a variable

Replace `with('messages','$messages')` with `with('messages', $messages)`. Notice the missing quotes in second argument.

Comment: yes sir before 10 minutes i found it, its fix my problem you are fabulous . thanks

Comment: sir i have a question i develop my website using wordpress (www.freeartflow.com) now im learning the laravel framwork to build like these websites , its a monthly payment membership for graphic resources (2d-3d-video temp) .   how can i learn to make this steps (recurrent membership) in the laravel ... can i do it ! and where !   I will be very grateful to you      ..... also can i create contributors  like www.freepik.com ....... many thanks

Comment: Check out [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/billing) for subscription payments and possibly [Laravel Spark](https://spark.laravel.com) for SaaS projects. Cheers!

Comment: can also make the payment with paypal rather than stripe

Comment: Yes, Braintree supports Paypal and Cashier supports Braintree

Comment: thank you sir very very much ,have a good day